# Multiline chart from dataframe using nvd3

Tags: python, pandas, nvd3.js

The nvd3 line chart in the example below uses python list as data source. But how to plot multiline from a pandas dataframe without explicitly stating the columns i.e. like in pandas plot: `df.plot()` df could contain `x` columns.

```
from nvd3 import lineChart

# Open File for test
output_file = open('test_lineChart.html', 'w')
# ---------------------------------------
type = "lineChart"
chart = lineChart(name=type, x_is_date=False, x_axis_format="AM_PM")

xdata = list(range(0, 24))
ydata = [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 4, 3, 3, 5, 7, 5, 3, 16, 6, 9, 15, 4, 12]
ydata2 = [9, 8, 11, 8, 3, 7, 10, 8, 6, 6, 9, 6, 5, 4, 3, 10, 0, 6, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]

kwargs1 = {'color': 'black'}
kwargs2 = {'color': 'red'}
extra_serie = {"tooltip": {"y_start": "There is ", "y_end": " calls"}}
chart.add_serie(y=ydata, x=xdata, name='sine', extra=extra_serie, **kwargs1)
extra_serie = {"tooltip": {"y_start": "", "y_end": " min"}}
chart.add_serie(y=ydata2, x=xdata, name='cose', extra=extra_serie, **kwargs2)

chart.buildhtml()

output_file.write(chart.htmlcontent)

# close Html file
output_file.close()
```

How to plot from this dataframe using nvd3:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.set_index('datetime')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df.plot(ax=ax, marker='o')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, the `chart` takes the data as `list`, so you would have to convert your `index` and `column` data to `list` like so (assuming your `column` names are `col1` and `col2` respectively:

```
def plot_nvd3(df, ydata='col1', ydata2='col2'):
    # Open File for test
    output_file = open('test_lineChart.html', 'w')
    # ---------------------------------------
    type = "lineChart"
    chart = lineChart(name=type, x_is_date=False, x_axis_format="AM_PM")

    xdata = df.index.tolist()
    ydata = df[ydata].tolist()
    ydata2 = df[ydata2].tolist()

    kwargs1 = {'color': 'black'}
    kwargs2 = {'color': 'red'}
    extra_serie = {"tooltip": {"y_start": "There is ", "y_end": " calls"}}
    chart.add_serie(y=ydata, x=xdata, name='sine', extra=extra_serie, **kwargs1)
    extra_serie = {"tooltip": {"y_start": "", "y_end": " min"}}
    chart.add_serie(y=ydata2, x=xdata, name='cose', extra=extra_serie, **kwargs2)

    chart.buildhtml()

    output_file.write(chart.htmlcontent)

    # close Html file
    output_file.close()
```

Usage would by:

```
plot_nvd3(df, 'col1', 'col2')
```

I have not checked how `nvd3` works with `DateTimeIndex`, though, in case your `df = df.set_index('datetime')` results in one.